# I want to extract the first five data that match the where clause from Laravel relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'd like to do something like this with Laravel's Eloquent:relationship, but it doesn't work.

```
$playlist->setRelation('tags', $playlist->tags->where('privacySetting', 'public')->take(5));
```

It works without where clause, but I want to retrieve the first 5 data in the tags relationship table that match the where clause.
How can I do this?

Laravel version is 7.28.1.

Answer (score 0):

this will select top 5 based on criteria from model

```
$playlist = Playlist::with(['tags' => function($filter){
  return $filter->where('privacySetting', 'public')
  ->take(5);
}])
->get();
//try dd($playlist);
```